# What controls are used instead of the DS4 Touchpad in the PC version?

Tags: pc, detroit-become-human

On the PS4 version of Detroit: Become Human, you use the Touchpad of the DualShock 4 for certain actions like painting and drawing holograms. On the PC version, you don't have the touchpad when you use a Mouse + Keyboard or an Xbox 360/Xbox One controller.

What controls are used instead of the Touchpad in the PC version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The touchscreen controls are replaced by analog joystick/mouse movements in the PC version.

Here's a clip from the PS4 version, showing where the touchscreen controls are used:

And here's an analogous moment from the PC version, where you can see these commands are transformed into joystick prompts:

Those prompts are performed with the right joystick on an XBox controller or by holding the left mouse button and moving the mouse in the correct direction.